# «Hoy toca(n) piernas»

Tags: concordancia-verbal

Esta mañana estaba hablando con un amigo sobre lo que iba a hacer en el gimnasio y le dije «hoy toca piernas».  Pero me puse a pensar, ¿por qué no es *tocan*?  Dudo mucho que *piernas* sea objeto directo, ya que me sonaría rarísimo decir *hoy las toca*.  Además en otras frases modificaría el verbo según lo que le sigue: *me toca un examen*, *me tocan dos exámenes*.  Sin duda es sujeto.

Una búsqueda por Google muestra que no soy el único en preferir el verbo singular en la expresión (lo mismo con «abdominales» o «brazos»): las formas en plural son una pequeña minoría, y las en singular una plena mayoría.

¿Cuál es la lógica?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

*Piernas* es una elipsis por *rutina de (ejercicio para las) piernas* o por el igualmente elíptico *hacer piernas*, que es como se suele decir.

No creo que haya muchos otros ejemplos similares, pero se me ocurre un diálogo como el que sigue, donde hay que suponer una persona que va a comer siempre lo mismo (pollo o pescado, digamos) pero cambiando el acompañamiento:

> —¿Qué preferiría Ud. hoy de guarnición?
>   —Hoy me gustaría papas fritas.

Esta falta de concordancia entre el verbo en singular *gustaría* y el sujeto en plural *papas fritas* me resulta totalmente natural en este contexto (y estoy seguro que yo debo emplear frases así todo el tiempo). *Papas fritas* en realidad es una elipsis de *una guarnición de papas fritas*.

Comment: Ya, eso pensaba (pero con otras frases elípticas, tipo «día de» pero resulta que hablantes hay que sí hacen la concordancia en plural. No obstante, como en el ejemplo de papas fritas, es interesante notar que no hay determinante, algo normalmente prohibido a los sujetos, que para mí favorece por mucho el análisis de elipsis.

Comment: Y no quiero especular más, pero la semántica seguro tiene que ver también: *papas fritas*, como *piernas*, no es realmente un conjunto de cosas: es un ente abstracto singular (guarnición de papas fritas, ejercicio de piernas) al cual etiquetamos así.

Comment: @pabladf76 tal vez pero también he encontrado otros ejemplos que no se contemplan como un ente singular pero que se emplea con singular. Creo que en casi todo caso con tocar, es posible interponer algún verbo (lo cual justificaría singular), tipo *toca (sufrir) dos exámenes*, *toca (jugar) los partidos*

Comment: Creo que simplemente el  verbo **tocar** usado en este sentido posibilita una elisión del verbo siguiente: "hoy toca **_hacer_** piernas", "hoy toca **_comer_** papas fritas", "mañana toca **_subir_** la montaña", etc....